# Structure of hyperbolic manifolds of finite volume

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be a hyperbolic manifold of finite volume.

**I want to prove that $X$ has ends of the form $N\times \mathbb{R}$ where $N$ has a finite covering by a nilmanifold and $\pi_1N\to \pi_1 X$ is injective.**

I have no idea about it. Why does $X$ have splitting ends and why does it have injectivity about fundamental groups? Could you please give some help with the detail? Thank you very much!

Comment: check the internet for "Margulis lemma" and "thin-thick decomposition".

Comment: Chapter IV of Benedetti-Petronio „Lectures on Hyperbolic Geometry“ has a complete proof.

Comment: If "hyperbolic" means "real hyperbolic", $N$ even has a finite covering by a torus.